# Where is the code which is called when you call getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android

I have looked into Android [sources](http://android.googlesource.com) just out of interest. What I found is that `Context` is an abstract class with abstract method:

```
public abstract Context getApplicationContext();
```

The `ContextWrapper.java` extends `Context.java` which led to implementation of `getApplicationContext()` method:

```
 @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return mBase.getApplicationContext();
    }
```

But `mBase` is reference to an object of type `Context` which is initialized in `ContextWrapper`'s constructor:

```
public ContextWrapper(Context base) {
    mBase = base;
}
```

So this `mBase` reference refers to `abstract` class? 
Well, I just don't understand where is the code which is executed when you call `getApplicationContext()` from your `Activity`.

Comment: Do you understand how abstract classes work? There's some concrete class somewhere which `extends Context`, and that's where the method is implemented.

Comment: I'm interested where it is, I understand how abstract classes work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an interesting example of polymorphism.

As long as your `base` extends `Context`, it has to provide an implementation of `getApplicationContext()`, which in the case of `ContextWrapper` is the code you provided here.  There's this implementation, and [the one in `ContextImpl`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl).

It's important to note a couple of things when reading the code you provided:  `ContextWrapper` itself extends `Context`, but it also takes a `Context` as an input (which could be a `ContextWrapper`, or a `Service`, or an `Application`, or an `Activity`).  `ContextWrapper` doesn't care which kind it is; it just knows that they have a method `getApplicationContext` and it wants to call that method when asked.  (For example, it could be passed another `ContextWrapper`, but because said `ContextWrapper` would also require a `Context` in its constructor, that would just add another level of nesting.)

The `Application extends ContextWrapper` class calls `super(null)`, which would mean that `getApplicationContext()` would throw a `NullPointerException` if it were left that way--however, in `ContextWrapper` it's also settable by `attachBaseContext(Context)`, and this is where it gets interesting.

Both `Activity` and `Application` have methods `attach(Context [...other stuff])`.  Each of them calls `attachBaseContext()` with the passed-in `Context`.

- In the `Instrumentation` class, you'll find [`android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication()`](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.1.1_r1@android%24app@Instrumentation@newApplication%28java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.String,android.content.Context%29&k=u), where a `ContextImpl` is created, and passed into an `Application`.
- In the `ActivityThread` class, you'll find [`handleBindApplication`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2008) which creates a `ContextImpl` that gets passed to the `Activity` as its root `Context`.
- In the `LoadedApk` class, you'll find `makeApplication` which creates a `ContextImpl` that gets passed to an `Application`.  [Here](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.1.1_r1@android%24app@LoadedApk@makeApplication%28boolean,android.app.Instrumentation%29&k=u) are the places it's called.

So, at the end of the day, `mBase` typically ends up as a `ContextImpl`.

Potentially useful links I looked at while finding all of this out:

- [Usages of `attach`](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.1.1_r1@android%24app@Activity@attach%28android.content.Context,android.app.ActivityThread,android.app.Instrumentation,android.os.IBinder,int,android.app.Application,android.content.Intent,android.content.pm.ActivityInfo,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.Activity,java.lang.String,android.app.Activity.NonConfigurationInstances,android.content.res.Configuration%29&k=u)
- [Usages of `attachBaseContext`](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.1.1_r1@android%24content@ContextWrapper@attachBaseContext%28android.content.Context%29&k=u)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jon. I'm confused because there is no implementation of this method nor in `Application.java` neither in `Service.java`. Where is the implementation?

Comment: The implementation is in `ContextWrapper`.  The key bit of information is that `mBase` changes at run-time as an Activity or Application is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed research and explanation!

Comment: This is hands down, the best SO post I've ever read about the relation between the ContextWrapper proxy object and the ContextImpl object (the real implementor of Context), and how classes such as Activity and Application interact with them. Thanks for the writeup Jon.